# Sending wave file in HttpResponse makes it corrupt

Tags: java, audio, download, wav, httpresponse

I am trying to read a wav file from the resources of my Java Spring project and then convert the file to a byte array and write it to outputstream of HttpResponse. When I receive the file from my web application it is broken with garbage data.

Here is the code in my servlet:

```
response.setContentType("audio/wav");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=audio-qrcode-"+"hellosine"+".wav");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "private");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")

URL helloSineWav = QRcodeController.class.getClassLoader().getResource("hellosine.wav");
byte[] audioBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(helloSineWav.openStream());
response.setContentLength(audioBytes.length);
ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
outStream.write( audioBytes );
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Another way I tried to approach the solution was:

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
is.close();
out.close();
```

Both approach work but give me a corrupted audio file at the other end. I am not exactly sure why this is happening. 
Is it something to do with the header?

Comment: Probably not an answer, but consider `IOUtils.copy((helloSineWav.openStream(), response.getOutputStream())`

Comment: You should pay attention to the binary format of the data you're sending. AFAIK Java output streams are big-endian, if your web app reads its data in little-endian you should reverse the bit order. Easy way to check that : send a 0x55 byte and verify that you don't receive a 0xAA.

Comment: Endian-ness is fine as when I check the data i can see the Riff and WAVEfmt tags in the file. The file has some extra corrupt data which is causing the problem, but I am not sure why that is happening. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I tried this but it gives me the same result.

Comment: Why are you setting the "Accept-ranges" header? It doesn't look like your code accepts ranges. If the browser were to request a range for your wav-file you would send it the whole file anyway. Do you get any requests for ranges?

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Yes I tried without it also, but it does not make any difference.

Comment: @ishan: If your code doesn't accept ranges, you shouldn't send the "Accept-ranges" header, so remove it. Otherwise your code will break when a client decides to request a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It wasn't really related to httpResponse or any of this. I added the wave file to the Java Project and packaged a war file from it. But when I deploy the project and the resource file gets unpacked it changes the size of the file from the original and introduces some garbage information. I am currently looking into why that happens. But as far as this question is concerned, when I replaced the wave file with the correct size one it works. Sorry for bothering you guys.